# ##[error]denied: Not Authorized when pushing docker image to AWS ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to push my Docker image to AWS ECR and I'm getting `Not Authorized` when trying to do so.

I have all of the required variables set as variables in Azure DevOps, which is what I'm using. So I'm not sure why it's not getting proper authentication.

Here's my YAML code:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
strategy:
  matrix:
    Python38:
      python.version: '3.8'

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '$(python.version)'
  displayName: 'Use Python $(python.version)'

- script: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip requests os smtplib datetime
    pip install -r requirements.txt
  displayName: 'Install dependencies'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: 
    Contents: '*'
    TargetFolder: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: true
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/project.zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- task: S3Upload@1
  inputs:
    awsCredentials: 'weather'
    regionName: 'us-west-2'
    bucketName: 'weather-update-project-bucket'
    sourceFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    globExpressions: '*project.zip*'
    targetFolder: 'python'
    createBucket: true

- script: |
    aws ecr get-login-password --region $(AWS_REGION) | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $(AWS_ACCOUNT_ID).dkr.ecr.$(AWS_REGION).amazonaws.com
  displayName: 'Login to AWS'
  env:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID)
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $(AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

- task: Docker@2
  inputs:
    repository: 'public.ecr.aws/u1c1h9j4/weather-update-project'
    command: 'buildAndPush'
    Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
    tags: 'latest'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use the [Amazon ECR Push task](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vsts/latest/userguide/ecr-pushimage.html) instead of the regular Docker push.

First, build the image with `Docker@2`:

```
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build an image
  inputs:
    command: build
    dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
    buildContext: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    tags: 'latest'
```

After that, push with `ECRPushImage@1`:

```
- task: ECRPushImage@1
  inputs:
    awsCredentials: 'weather'
    regionName: us-west-2
    imageSource: 'imagename'
    sourceImageName: 'YOUR-IAMGE-NAME'
    sourceImageTag: 'latest'
    pushTag: 'latest'
    repositoryName: 'YOUR-AWS-ECR-REPO'
```

Comment: One thing I couldn’t figure out from before is the image name- when I run the “build an image” task, what’s the name of the image when it gets created?

Comment: @MP32 you can use the `repository` flag in the build step. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops#build-and-push